# Does Craft CMS have an API?

Tags: plugin-development, routes

Does Craft CMS have an API that third-party webapps can access?

Maybe a REST API which you can log in to and send GET, PUT, POST, DELETE commands to, from a third-party app?

It seems like it should have an API, by the statement of the creator:

> A key part of the architecture is our service layer. All of the
>   business logic in Craft happens in service classes, which provide APIs
>   that anything else in the system (including other services) can talk
>   to.
>    - http://www.thenerdary.net/post/48123188844/interview-with-brandon-kelly-creator-of-craft

But then again, some other people who have tried integrating towards Craft CMS says it doesn't:

> I ran into some trouble with the API. Shit, Craft doesn’t freakin’
>   have one! I assumed it would, oops.. So I researched how to do it. I
>   knew I could probably fake it and output json using template tags but
>   no-one wants to do that. I looked at some API controllers but non of
>   them worked very well. In the end I found a nice plugin called JSON
>   Expand that converts entries from Twig into JSON. - 
>   http://abandon.ie/notebook/using-angularjs-with-craft-cms

I'm confused. If it has an API, what kind is it, and what protocol does it use? REST? SOAP? RPC? Something else?

And where is it documented? A simple 'hello world' or 'transmit som data into Craft CMS' example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Craft doesn't have a REST API (edit: or any other web service) built-in. The "API" mentioned in the first quote (and elsewhere related) would be the more generic meaning of the term and refers to the [service layer](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference#craft.app.services).

With a very consistent MVC based architecture based on [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/), Craft is well suited for REST implementation, though. See [this G+ thread](https://plus.google.com/108374347584100012430/posts/3v9MSFhT8nr) for P&T weighing in on the subject.

As a native REST API isn't part of the core, one would have to added to Craft via a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction).

There's at least [one plugin out there](https://github.com/wesrice/rest-easy), though I haven't tried it (or any others) myself.

**Edit**

It should be mentioned that after I wrote the above answer, Pixel and Tonic has released the [Element API plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) - making it easy to build a REST API with Craft. Element API is pretty basic (only GET requests), but can probably be extended with a custom plugin to support additional HTTP methods.

P&T has also stated that they want Craft 3 to have a full, built-in REST API at some point.

Comment: So when he says "including other services" then he is not talking about third party services?

Comment: No, as in "other Craft services", would be my interpretation. Notice the "anything else _in the system_" part.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense.

Comment: Do you know if it has any other kind of API for third-parties? SOAP? RPC?

Comment: No, there aren't any web services shipped with Craft. Might be worth a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests).

Comment: You might want to look into [what Yii has to offer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice), though.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into rest-easy, and maybe using cURL to simulate a normal user interacting with Craft CMS and POST'ing the data through the forms inside the CMS itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23077/discussion-between-mmikkel-and-magne).

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to create a JSON API for fetching existing entries, etc., check out the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin.